# How to reset business hours in Facebook Pages API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I started looking into the Facebook Pages API.
What I am currently missing is any way of resetting or removing already existing business hours.

What I tried already:

- Not sending any business hours at all
- Using "none" (suggested in another question, like: `{"mon_1_open": "none", "mon_1_close": "none"}`
- Setting both the opening and closing hours to "00:00" (like `{"mon_1_open": "00:00", "mon_1_close": "00:00"}`

Unfortunately, none of those requests (even though they caused a 200 response) caused the existing business hours to change.

What am I doing wrong? Does anyone of you have a hint?

Best,
Lennart

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#Updating: _“If one specific day is open 24 hours, the range should be specified as 00:00 to 24:00.”_ - have you tried that?

Comment: @CBroe thanks, but I am actually trying to do the opposite. I want a page to be closed for the entire day instead of open.

Comment: Then leave that particular day out of the JSON completely, and specify only the rest?

Comment: @CBroe unfortunately doesn't work as well :/ this will keep the business hours for that day untouched. I think it's weird that this is not covered by the docs at all.

Comment: I tested it, and for me it removed the hours that were set for a specific day, when I leave that day completely out of the JSON.

Comment: Just tested. Not sending the hours for a specific day or sending `none` will both remove hours from that day. But sending `none` for all days will do nothing. Looks like the API will not let you remove all opening hours. Whereas this is possible in the Facebook Business page

Comment: if you want to set a day as closed you simply do not write it, you do not need to do either of them: {"mon_1_open": "none", "mon_1_close": "00:00"}, just do not write anything as Monday for example.